# Is there a way to make an element 'transparent' to clicks, but maintain the :hover and :active css styles?

Tags: html, css, click

I have an image with `button`s overlain on it. Because the `button`s are semitransparent, and I don't want the labels to be, I've overlaid a span on each button (with 100% opacity). To make sure that the `span`s don't intercept all the clicks, I used the `pointer-events: none;` css property on the `span`s.

Here's the structure of the markup (Jade):

```
div.slide
    div.controls.buttons
        button.move.forward
        button.move.back
        button.info
    div.controls.icons
        span.move.forward.icon.ion-chevron-right
        span.move.back.icon.ion-chevron-left
        span.info.icon.ion-information
```

`.icon.ion-*` are styles for the [ionicon icon font](http://ionicons.com/)

It looks like this when rendered:

[image: slide-with-overlay]

The problem is, that because I have `pointer-events:none;`, I can't use `:hover` or `:active` on the `.icons span`. Is there a way to propogate the click event to the element below without using `pointer-events: none`?

Am I going to have to put a listener on each button then trigger the click event using javascript? Or is there a nicer way?

**[Codepen example here](http://codepen.io/redders6600/pen/fJnra)**

Comment: The `:active` state is often only triggered by a click.

Comment: yes - that's my problem. Can I still have the active state on the overlying span but propogate the click to the button below?

Comment: Ah, I understand what you mean now. I think you'll have to do this with JavaScript but I can't say for certain.

Comment: Show a live example, jsfiddle or something, please.

Comment: Javascript events will by default bubble through all layers as shown in http://jsfiddle.net/rwAa5/ . I'm not really sure what the problem is, can you explain a bit further how your case differs from my fiddle?

Comment: http://codepen.io/redders6600/pen/fJnra  -- this is a fiddle with an example.

Comment: Instead of lowering the opacity of the button you could just make the bakcground-color transparent `background: rgba(0,0,0, 0.5);` that way you can just have the text inside the button. [link with examples](http://css-tricks.com/rgba-browser-support/).

Comment: @NatalieH Very good point. Seems so obvious now. Happy to accept this is you wanted to turn it into an answer.